# Spreading cell values into columns using UNIX

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Suppose we have this file:

```
head file

id,name,value
1,Je,1
2,Je,1
3,Ko,1
4,Ne,1
5,Ne,1
6,Je,1
7,Ko,1
8,Ne,1
9,Ne,1
```

And I'd like to get this out:

```
id,Je,Ko,Ne
1,1,0,0
2,1,0,0
3,0,1,0
4,0,0,1
5,0,0,1
6,1,0,0
7,0,1,0
8,0,0,1
9,0,0,1
```

Does someone know how to get this output, using awk or sed?

Comment: Are values possible other than Je, Ko, or Ne?

Comment: Where are the zeros coming from ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the possible values of `name` are only Je or Ko or Ne, you can do:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{print "id,Je,Ko,Ne"}
         NR==1{ next }
         {je=$2=="Je"?"1":"0"; 
          ko=$2=="Ko"?"1":"0";
          ne=$2=="Ne"?"1":"0";
          print $1","je","ko","ne}' file
```

If you want something that will print the values in the same order they are read and not limited to your example fields, you could do:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS; x=1;y=1}
NR==1 { next }

!($2 in oa){ oa[$2]=1; ar[x++]=$2}

{lines[y++]=$0;}

END{
    s="";
    for (i=1; i<x; i++)
         s=s==""?ar[i]:s OFS ar[i];
    print "id" OFS s;   
    for (j=1; j<y; j++){
        split(lines[j], a)
        s=""
        for (i=1; i<x; i++) {
           tt=ar[i]==a[2]?"1":"0"   
           s=s==""?tt:s OFS tt;
         } 
         print a[1] OFS s;
    }
 }
'   file
```

Comment: You're right, but I'd like to receive a more general answer. Suppose 'Je','Ko', and 'Ne' are just examples, and there are further values.

Comment: The main challenge with that is whether the values can be known in advance. If you can enumerate the values at the start of the script, you know how many columns there will be, and so you can print as soon as you read a line. If not, you will basically need to read the entire file into memory, which is usually doable, but the code will be a lot peskier.

Comment: Duh, you were typing while I was typing (-:

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "two-pass solution" (along the lines suggested by @Drakosha) implemented using a single invocation of `awk`. The implementation would be a little simpler if there was no requirement regarding the ordering of names.

```
awk -F, '
  # global: n, array a
  function println(ix,name,value,  i,line) { 
    line=ix;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
      if (a[i]==name) {line=line OFS value} else {line=line OFS 0}
    }
    print line;
  }
  BEGIN {OFS=FS; n=0}
  FNR==1 {next}  # skip the header each time
  NR==FNR {if (!mem[$2]) {mem[$2] = a[n++] = $2}; next}
  !s { s="id"; for (i=0;i<n;i++) {s=s OFS a[i]}; print s}
  {println($1, $2, $3)}
  ' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest 2 passes.

- 1st will generate all the possible values of column 2 (Je, Ko, Ne,
  ...).
- 2nd will be able to trivially generate the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{s="Je,Ko,Ne";print "id,"s}
  NR>1 {m=s; sub($2,1,m); gsub("[^0-9,]+","0",m); print $1","m}' file
```